# Affect other element's child's style on hover

Tags: css

I could do this with Javascript but I how would I go about achieving this with CSS only:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Hover <a href="#info">me</a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th id="info">
            Info
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

All I want is when the anchor link gets hovered on, the table header "info" gets affected. And these are what I've tried to no avail:

```
a:hover #info
{  
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover table tr > th#info
{  
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this by selecting the link but you can target the parent `tr`

This is because there is [**no parent selector**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) or [**previous sibling selector**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

```css
tr:hover + tr th#info {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: red;
}
a {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Hover <a href="#info">me</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th id="info">
      Info
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Any explanation on why it won't work for the TR's child? Because I may want to add more elements/anchors inside the TD, targeting this #info, but if that's not possible then too bad...

Comment: I suggest you check the links I supplied...basically you can't select upwards in the DOM or children of other parents.

Comment: OK, Javascript to go then. That's really too bad, but thanks though!